# Seven Segment Display error java

Tags: java, user-interface

Hi when ever i run my program i get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at seven.segmeng.display.test.MultiCharacterDisplay.main(MultiCharacterDisplay.java:68)
Java Result: 1
```

there is a portion of the code which i'm not sure about which i am not sure about and it's linked to the error from the output

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = args[0];

        MultiCharacterDisplay display = new MultiCharacterDisplay(text.length(), Color.GREEN);
        display.setText(text);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBackground(Color.black);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(display);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

I'm not sure where to go at this point.

here is the multicharacter display code segment

```
public MultiCharacterDisplay(int segmentDisplayCount, Color segmentColor) {
        this.segmentDisplayCount = segmentDisplayCount;
        segmentDisplays = new ArrayList<SixteenSegmentDisplay>(segmentDisplayCount);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, GAP, 0));
        for (int i = 0; i < segmentDisplayCount; i++) {
            SixteenSegmentDisplay display = new SixteenSegmentDisplay();
            display.setSegmentColor(segmentColor);
            segmentDisplays.add(display);
            add(display);
        }
    }
```

here is the segmentdisplaycount section

```
public class MultiCharacterDisplay extends JComponent {
    private static final int GAP = 5;
    private int segmentDisplayCount;
    private List<SixteenSegmentDisplay> segmentDisplays;

    public MultiCharacterDisplay(int segmentDisplayCount) {
        this(segmentDisplayCount, Color.red);
    }

    public MultiCharacterDisplay(int segmentDisplayCount, Color segmentColor) {
        this.segmentDisplayCount = segmentDisplayCount;
        segmentDisplays = new ArrayList<SixteenSegmentDisplay>(segmentDisplayCount);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, GAP, 0));
        for (int i = 0; i < segmentDisplayCount; i++) {
            SixteenSegmentDisplay display = new SixteenSegmentDisplay();
            display.setSegmentColor(segmentColor);
            segmentDisplays.add(display);
            add(display);
        }
```

Comment: post the code of MultiCharacterDisplay. The exception occurs there.

Comment: i think you used an array.

Comment: Either post the code of MultiCharacterDisplay class or post what is there at line no 68?

Comment: could i know value of segmentDisplayCount